# capistrano failing to precompile assets with "rake stdout: Nothing written"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

When trying to deploy I get that error and I don't know the source of problem.

It's strange, because if I ssh to server and try to precompile assets manually, everything is fine.

Is there a way to trace that bug. I think it's a bug, because I've already deployed several times to that machine and everything was perfect.

Comment: Have you tried the --trace option to get more detailed output?  Also, I would suggest that you look at the exact command capistrano is running (and order) to see if you can reproduce the error.

Comment: Yes, I tried --trace, it gives some notices, but no useful information. It seems, that assets are precompiling, but Capistrano can't catch output.

Comment: Looking at this issue: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/895 and its linked issue here https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/100 it seems that there is a known issue about this. However, it seems that the error is still real and its just that it doesn't capture the error message.  I would still take the actual command and try to execute it manually to see if that returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, why it failed. It was due to hi CPU consumption, system just killed it without any warnings. So I just stopped some processes, that consumed CPU as well, and everything compiled.

Comment: I had something similar, but it would happen intermittently, which made it even more confusing. I was maxing out on RAM.